# VBA-get values with known cell address

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to achive the values of a row holding specific text. Say Liquidity Coverage Ratio is the text that is available in B57. I need the value of C57 and D57. I have achieved until retreiving the address of the cell holding text.

Kindly help me progressing further.

> ```
>  If fCheckSheet(forecastWorkbook, "Calculator (FX net)") Then
>             wsForecast.Activate
>         Else
>             ErrorStatus = "Source Sheet:Calculator (FX net) not found"
>             msgBoxReturn = MsgBox(ErrorStatus & forecastWorkbook.FullName, vbExclamation + vbOKCancel)
>      End If
>
>      Set rngRatio = FindRangeOfText(wsForecast, "Liquidity Coverage Ratio")
>      'Gets the address of cell having
>      RatioAddress = rngRatio.Address
>
>      'The address is $B$57
>        '???? how to retreive values for $c$57 and $D$57
> ```

I really appreciate the response from stackoverflow users who made me grow from novice until this level. Thanks for your patience.

Regards,

Mani

Comment: Hi Manivannan, I assume you already know this, but in case you didn't, the VLOOKUP formula would do this job as well. If you need to do this programatically, you can call VLOOKUP with Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup method and you don't have to rewrite the lookup function:)

Comment: I need a professional VBA code. Vlookup is heavy weight component which will write the formula to every single cell we perform the action. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the functions you refer to (but did not provide the code to support) will return `Range` type object (or `Nothing`), then you can simply use the `Offset` method:

```
If Not rngRatio Is Nothing Then
    With rngRatio
        Debug.Print .Offset(0,1).Address, .Offset(0,1).Value '$C$57
        Debug.Print .Offset(0,2).Address, .Offset(0,2).Value '$D$57
    End With
End If
```

There is also a lesser-known way to do the same thing:

```
If Not rngRatio Is Nothing Then
    With rngRatio
        Debug.Print .Cells(1, 2).Value 
        Debug.Print .Cells(1, 3).Value
    End With
End With
```

My preference is for the first method, because it is explicit rather than implicit. This method is less clear, because not everyone knows intuitively that you can reference a cell *outside* of a range object, using the `Cells` property, such as:

```
MsgBox Range("A1").Cells(1, 4).Address ' --> $E$1

MsgBox Range("A1").Cells(4, 2).Address ' --> $B$4
```

Comment: Simple words,But worth it. You're a star. Thank you so much. The function  FindRangeOfText returns as range. Absloutely working!!!